# Laravel - How to pass cached value to multiple views without extra requests?

Tags: laravel, performance, optimization, view, service-provider

Have several data collections that are retrieved from cache and need to be passed to several different views. 
For performance optimization need them to be retrieved only once, without extra requests to cache.

So **using ViewComposer is not an option** - it fires request to cache for each listed view.

Using following solution in AppServiceProvider :

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('somedata', Cache::get('somekey')); 
    }
```

But in this case data passed to all views, which is not good from perspective of memory consumption. 
Need ability to pass data only to certain views. (not pages, as those views are used on almost every page)
Something like following:
view(['viewname1', 'viewname2'])->share('somedata', Cache::get('somekey'));

Comment: you can list the views to use the shared variable in viewComposer. You just choose the easy one which shares the variables with all views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views). Example below taken from documentation.

Register the view composer in your AppServiceProvider and specify the routes it should be attached to;

```
View::composer(
    ['profile', 'dashboard'], // the routes you want to share it with
    'App\Http\View\Composers\MyViewComposer' // your registered view composer
);
```

In your View Composer, get your cached variable and pass it to the views;

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $someData = Cache::get('somekey');

    $view->with($someData);
}
```

Comment: In this case it will fire request to Cache for each view

Comment: Only on specified routes.